# Overlapping counts for a specific time range

Tags: sql, datetime, time, overlap, between

I have a query where I am trying to find the amount of times something was viewed within a certain time range on a database.

**This is my query so far:**

```
USE DB1
SELECT DISTINCT NAME,
COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM LOGS
WHERE EVENT = 'Viewed'
AND TIME BETWEEN '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-07-24 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY COUNT DESC;
```

This query is successful in telling me how many times something was viewed within that 3 month range, however when I shorten the time range to three different queries with that specific line changing from:

```
TIME BETWEEN '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-05-22 00:00:00.000';
TIME BETWEEN '2015-05-22 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-06-22 00:00:00.000';
TIME BETWEEN '2015-06-22 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-04-24 00:00:00.000';
```

Then when I add up the distinct values, they are not equal. In fact they are much higher to the amount of rows I get with the very first query in the three month range. I am assuming that some values are overlapping. How can I get around this? I have checked my work and I am pretty sure the first query gives me the correct amount of rows within the time range, but I need more specific data

Answer (score 0):

`col BETWEEN a AND b` is computed to `a <= col <= b`, so you have a overlapping interval in your time-ranges

Change this from midnight to one sec before midnight:

```
TIME BETWEEN '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-04-22 23:59:59.999';
TIME BETWEEN '2015-05-22 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-05-22 23:59:59.999';
TIME BETWEEN '2015-06-22 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-04-24 23:59:59.999';
```

**Update**

Try this:

```
TIME BETWEEN '2015-04-22 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-22 23:59:59';
TIME BETWEEN '2015-05-22 00:00:00' AND '2015-05-22 23:59:59';
TIME BETWEEN '2015-06-22 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-24 23:59:59';
```

Comment: What coltype is `TIME`?

Comment: The datatype for TIME is datetime

Comment: did you try my updated answer? MySQL cant process milisecs in `TIME`, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html

Comment: That is just giving me one day, I need the entire month's data. and I believe that dates are off.

Comment: It is also giving more rows than my previous queries. I am on MS SQL Server 08

Comment: Try to select by `year(TIME) = 2015 and month(TIME) = 4` without `BETWEEN`

Comment: I have never seen that method, how would the query look like

Comment: `WHERE EVENT = 'Viewed' AND year(TIME) = 2015 and month(TIME) = 4`

Comment: So. I have figured out the answer to my own question. The reason why the DISTINCT monthly values are not adding up, are because they are in fact...DISTINCT. Let's say there are 5 distinct total values for 3 months. The first month can have 4 of those distinct values viewed, the second month can have 3, and the third month just 1 value viewed. That is not 8 DISTINCT values, but 8 variations of the 5 Distinct values spread out monthly.

Comment: I was simply thinking of it in the wrong terms, Thank you everyone for your time and answers

Answer (score 0):

```
X BETWEEN Y AND Z
```

translates to

```
X >= Y AND X <= Z
```

So you should use different queries for periods within full range, something like:

```
TIME >= '2015-04-22 00:00:00.000' AND TIME < '2015-05-22 00:00:00.000';
TIME >= '2015-05-22 00:00:00.000' AND TIME < '2015-06-22 00:00:00.000';
TIME >= '2015-06-22 00:00:00.000' AND TIME <= '2015-07-24 00:00:00.000';
```

Logic for last time period is up to you... you can for example rearrange it to:

```
TIME >= '2015-06-22 00:00:00.000' AND TIME < '2015-07-25 00:00:01.000';
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however this is giving me the same exact output as the BETWEEN command.